# How to run headless program and Windows form at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making Chatting program with C# .Net. I want to run TCP server when I press a button in windows form. TCP server is headless(dialogue will show to the Windows Form)

Now I made C# project(Windows Form Application), but I don't know 'what template is useful to run headless program' and 'how I run headless program by press the button in Windows form'. what are the right choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of choices for a headless server in order of preference

1. Windows Service
2. Console app

As for which is *"right"*, that is up to you to discover.